# Who composed the soundtrack for the Brave Wii game?

Tags: nintendo-wii, brave

*Brave*, for the Wii, has different music than the movie soundtrack. Who composed the music for the game?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I first emailed Disney Interactive Support, who pointed me towards the developers of the game:

> Unfortunately, we here at Disney Interactive Support do not have any insight on the details of the game's development, such as who was involved in music composition. With this said, we encourage you to contact the Development Team for the game, Behavior Interactive. Below is a link to their website:
>
> http://www.bhvr.com/
>   - <sub>Disney Interactive Support</sub>

Upon contacting Behavior Interactive, the response I got stated that **Philippe Charron** created the music.

They also mentioned that

> [The Brave soundtrack] isn't available for download/purchase. [However] you can find some audio extracted [here on MusicAddict](http://musicaddict.ca/2013/03/brave-new-world-the-music-of-brave-the-game/).
>   - <sub>Behavior Interactive</sub>

Having read through that MusicAddict article, most of the OST appears to be on this [**SoundCloud**](https://soundcloud.com/behaviour-interactive/sets/brave-the-game), which was linked at the bottom of the article.